# Ansible: Failed to import the required Python library (influxdb) on localhost when trying to use influxdb_write

Tags: ansible, influxdb

I've got the following ansible playbook and influxdb running on my local machine.
I simply want to try writing something to my local influxdb using ansible. The idea here would be to create a table called connections with columns host, region and time.

```
---
- name: Influx test
  hosts: PE
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Write points into database
    influxdb_write:
      hostname: "localhost"
      database_name: "test"
      data_points:
        - measurement: connections
          tags:
            host: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
            region: test-region
          time: "test time"
```

PE looks like this:

```
[PE]
local ansible_host=localhost ansible_connection=local hostname=Lab_R1 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

Turns out that when I run my playbook I get:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_influxdb_write_payload_v07tkyyd/ansible_influxdb_write_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/influxdb.py", line 23, in <module>
    from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'influxdb'
fatal: [local]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "data_points": [
                {
                    "measurement": "connections",
                    "tags": {
                        "host": "local",
                        "region": "test-region"
                    },
                    "time": "test time"
                }
            ],
            "database_name": "test",
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "password": "root",
            "port": 8086,
            "proxies": {},
            "retries": 3,
            "ssl": false,
            "timeout": null,
            "udp_port": 4444,
            "use_udp": false,
            "username": "root",
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (influxdb) on localhost.localdomain's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
}
```

Comment: Do you have the Python `influxdb` module installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [`influxdb_write` module requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/influxdb_write_module.html#requirements), python library influxdb >= 0.9 is required.

This requirement is needed on the target of the task, which is in your case `localhost`.

So you need to [install influxdb python library](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/include-readme.html#id3) with the method of your choice (system package or `pip`).